# Foreign key not showing in GET request spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am doing GET request "/api/admin/tickets". I am not getting userId in response. I have checked the database and userId is present there. In entity "Ticket" userId should act as a foreign key. I don't know why I am not able to see foreign key in response. I am trying to establish one to many relationship between User and Ticket.

**TicketController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = Constants.ORIGIN)
public class TicketController {

    @Autowired
    private TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    @GetMapping("/admin/tickets")
    public Page<Ticket> getAllTickets(Pageable pageable) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        return ticketRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String businessUnit;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    public User() {
    }

    // constructor with fields
    // getters and setters

}
```

**Ticket.java**

```
@Entity
public class Ticket extends AuditModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ticketId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    public Ticket() {
        super();
    }

    public Ticket(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**TicketRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer>{

    Page<Ticket> findByUserId(Integer userId, Pageable pageable);
    Optional<Ticket> findByIdAndUserId(Integer ticketId, Integer userId);

}
```

Comment: First there is @JsonIgnore annotation which mean exclude from response.
Second user is defined as a lazy  association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You annotated the `User` field in the `Ticket` class with `@JsonIgnore`, this prevents the `User` data fom being included in the GET response.

The second problem might be that you load the `User` field lazily using `FetchType.LAZY`. This may also prevent the data from being included in the GET response.

Comment: Lazy won't, but `@JsonIgnore` definitely does.